# Assign value to field using if function in access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an access based form which aim at allowing users to enter records into my database.

Now I need to set some validation to the value entered in one of the fields. 
I want the user's to enter "3101 or 3102 or 3103 or 3104 or 3105", if anything else a part from the numeric values stated above is entered into that field, then the field should be assigned to a default value value of "0000".

Answer (score 0):

First, set the `DefaultValue` of the textbox to: 0

Also, set the `Format` property to: "0000"

Then use the AfterUpdate event of the textbox:

```
Dim InputValue As Integer
InputValue = Nz(Me!YourTextbox.Value, 0)
If InputValue  < 3101 or InputValue  > 3105 Then
    Me!YourTextbox.Value = Me!YourTextbox.DefaultValue
End If
```